# Test Stopwatch app on Google Glass Launcher on Samsung s4 device

Tags: android, google-glass

I've installed GDK on my eclipse. I've imported sample stopwatch app on eclipse.

Now i want to test this app on my Samsung S4 device(4.4.2).

How to test this app ?

I've read below thread,

http://liliputing.com/2013/05/run-google-glass-apps-on-a-nexus-7-tablet.html

and i've downloaded glass launcher app and installed from https://github.com/zhuowei/Xenologer

Glass launcher is working on my device and google voice search also working. but camera not working on my device.

Now I run the stopwatch project, it gets installed and then says DONE, however, I don't see any related command on the google glass launcher.

How to test this?

Answer (score 0):

At least as of now, those packages don't seem to have been updated for XE16, which introduced a number of major changes in the platform, in the GDK interfaces, and in how the GDK works. The sample apps have been updated to reflect these changes.

You may wish to try and load the XE12 version of the app (which should still be available in github), but this won't help much for developing applications for the Glass devices that are actually out there.